# Running Composer script events from a PHP script

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm currently writing an install script for our platform, and it needs to be able to create a `composer.json` file, and then run Composer. I've done that and it works fine, for the most part. The issue I'm having is that one of our dependencies runs a task upon installation of every subsequent package (for copying over config yaml files to the main project's directory), using Composer's `script` option. So for instance, in the generated Composer.json file is a bit that looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-package-install": [
        "Super\\Cool\\Task::postInstall"
    ],
    "pre-package-update": [
        "Super\\Cool\\Task::preUpdate"
    ],
    "post-package-update": [
        "Super\\Cool\\Task::postUpdate"
    ]
},
```

If I delete the vendor folder and then run Composer manually within the directory, the events work fine, but running it from my install script leaves me with an error message of

`Class Super\Cool\Task is not autoloadable, can not call post-package-install script`.

My only feeling is that perhaps Composer is trying to run its autoloader from the location of within my script, rather than the location of the composer.json file, but that's just a hunch

Does anyone know a way around this? Or is this a bug within Composer?

Comment: Are you sure you added required namespaces to `composer.json`'s `autoload` element?

Comment: The script that youre actually running.. is this a Composer event script or is this an external thing? If external are you trying to invoke composer with `exec` or similar or are you trying to load up the PHP infrastructure and then work directly with the composer Object(s)?

Comment: And did you try running that command manually? https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#running-scripts-manually

Comment: Also I have one project which generates some classes in install / update. Tasks are wrapped in a PHP executable script (`bin/generate`): https://github.com/thunderer/SimilarWebApi/blob/master/composer.json . Maybe try this approach?

Comment: @prodigitalson I'm running it with `popen()` so that I can still display composer's output

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk It should be autoloading anyway as it's in `vendor`, but I tried manually setting it anyway and it made no difference. I can't run this particular command manually as it appears Composer doesn't allow you to do that with `post-package-install`, presumably because it needs an event instance. Running it with a bin script might work, but I'd need to loop through the dependencies in the composer.json to work out where to copy the configs from, right?

Comment: @ThomasJ I remember having similar problems with such script handler class, seems like I solved it just like that.

Comment: Also documentation states that Composer uses PSR-0 autoloader, please debug it to see what happens when it attempts to load your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an update, it turns out this was an issue that has already been fixed. Running `composer self-update` fixed it